# Difference between get{return x} and return x

Tags: c#

If I create this piece of C# code:

```
using System;
public class Test
{
   private string x;
   public string GetX
   {
       get
       {
          return x;
       }
   }
}
```

What would the difference between the above and this:

```
using System;
public class Test
{
   private string x;
   public string GetX
   {
       return x;
   }
}
```

Comment: I do not think that the second example will compile

Comment: at least you will see the difference if you tried running the code first.

Comment: -1 for not even trying to compile the example code.

Comment: In a quick guess, the second example wont' compile... Statements inside the first example would make it a property type whereas no get/set in second example would expect it to be a function, which is wrong by the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume  you mean this for the second

```
using System;
public class Test
{
  private string x;
  public string GetX()
  {
    return x;
  }
}
```

In which case it is a method that returns a `string` while your first example is a `readonly` property

Answer (score 0):

Your second code snippet does not compile as it is neither a property nor a method.

we can not compare two un equal code snippets.